# Support CocoaPod and Carthage

Tags: ios, github, frameworks, cocoapods, carthage

I've created and published a Cocoapod using `pod lib create`. Now I also want to support Carthage, but after adding the path to the GitHub project to my `Cartfile` and running `carthage update --platform iOS` I'm getting the following error:

`Dependency "" has no shared framework schemes for any of the platforms: iOS`

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem :(

Answer (score 1):

#### How it should work:

To add support for Carthage for your existing CocoaPods library you need to share the scheme of your CocoaPods project. To do that you have to:

1. Open the workspace that contains your pod (it should contain example and Pods projects).
2. Go to `Product` > `Scheme` > `Manage Schemes`.
3. Select the Shared checkbox for your pod scheme (scheme with the name of your library in Pods project).

Test if the scheme builds successfully by running `carthage build --no-skip-current`.

#### Possible problems

If you created your pod using `pod lib create` you might see that all schemes are already shared but `carthage build --no-skip-current` still fails with error message:
`Dependency "" has no shared framework schemes for any of the platforms: iOS`

This is because Xcode shows that the schemes are shared but the `.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/YourProjectName.xcscheme` file that marks the scheme as shared is missing. To fix this just uncheck and check the scheme sharing checkbox and the file should be created. Now you just need to commit and push the file to your repository.

Comment: It looks like the problem with `pod lib create` is not the absence of shared scheme, but the absence of _framework target_